# How to use JSON_ARRAYAGG in EF Core Linq?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

**Student Class**

```
public class Student
{
    public string ClassId { get; set; }
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Student List**

```
[
    { 
        classId: 'A',
        studentId: '1',
        name: 'Mike'
     },
     { 
        classId: 'A',
        studentId: '2',
        name: 'Tom'
     },
     { 
        classId: 'B',
        studentId: '1',
        name: 'Alice'
     },
     { 
        classId: 'B',
        studentId: '2',
        name: 'Lisa'
     },
     { 
        classId: 'C',
        studentId: '1',
        name: 'Tow'
     },
]
```

**How I can get it like that in EF core?**

```
[
    { 
        classId: 'A',
        studentId: '1',
        name: 'Mike',
        friends: [
            { 
                studentId: '1',
                name: 'Mike'
            }, 
            {
                studentId: '2',
                name: 'Tom'
            }
        ]
     },
     { 
        classId: 'A',
        studentId: '2',
        name: 'Tom',
        friends: [
            { 
                studentId: '1',
                name: 'Mike'
            }, 
            {
                studentId: '2',
                name: 'Tom'
            }
        ]
     },
...
]
```

Set friends field with classmate list.
How I can get it with EF core Linq?

I made raw query like that, but can't traslate it to linq.

SELECT ClassId, StudentId, Name,
JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("studentId", StudentId, "name", Name) FROM Student;

Comment: Isn't that just db.Students? Your Student class in your model doesn't look right. It should also have a navigation property for a self join like List<Student> Friends. Then simply it would be db.Students where a particular student.Friends return a list of friends. BTW, your raw query also doesn't look right. Maybe you would want to provide some real data along with what your backend is (postgreSQL?).

Comment: Only in [EF Core 7](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22957)